# How to select whole 'camelCaseWord' in Pycharm with camel humps turned on

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

I have use camel humps option turned on in pycharm so I can move between 'camelled' words using ctr + ->/<- but sometimes I want to select the whole 
CameledWord I can't do shift + ctr + -> because it will select the first word in the camelled word.

example : 
I have this word : ImCamelCase 
I want to select the whole word : ImCamelCase 
using ctr + shift + -> does not work because I have camel humps option turned
on (and I need this option to remain turned on)

How can I do it (without turning off camelHumps option) ?

Answer (score 4):

Just found a solution :

using (ctr + w) two times will select the wholeCamelCased word

I think it is the best option if you have another idea tell me :)

Answer (score 4):

There is an option under Preferences->Editor->general to honor (or not) camel humps words when selecting on double click.

I realise this doesn't answer your question as you want to select it with keyboard shortcut but wanted to mention it anyways just in case you (or other readers) sometimes also want to select it using the cursor.